# Current_user always nil

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, devise, token

I have implemented a website containing devise. 
By overriding the devise/sessions controller I can sign_in and receive a token. It's working when I try to use it via browser ather sign `http://localhost:3000/api/v1/tasks.json -H 'Authorization: Token token="N8N5MPqFNdDz3G1jRsC9"'`

But whenever I try to use android app and also terminal `curl http://localhost:3000/api/v1/tasks.json -H 'Authorization: Token token="N8N5MPqFNdDz3G1jRsC9"'`, I get  message `{"error":"You need to sign in or sign up before continuing."}* Closing connection 1`
I don't know how many pages I have visited for possible solutions.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Your devise strategy for the token authentication would be helpful to provide you with an answer.

Comment: i m using mongoid , when i add devise strategy  i get error message /home/silver/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require': cannot load such file -- devise/strategies/token_authenticatable (LoadError)